# Как сделать цикл в цикле С++

Tags: c++

Передо мной поставлена задача: я должен организовать вывод чисел в форме матрицы и обеспечить приравнивание столбца матрицы к строчке. Я знаю, что я должен сделать цикл в цикле. 1 цикл будет проверять столбец, а 2 будет искать такую же строчку. Вот только проблема: я не знаю, как это сделать и как правильно записать код.

Мне надо сделать это для матрицы NxN, и искать я должен одинаковые строчки и столбцы. Также программа в конце должна вывести количество одинаковых столбцов и строк. Например, матрица 3х3:

```
1 2 3 
2 3 1 
3 2 1
```

Вот поскольку в этой матрице одинаковые первый столбец и первая строка, то в конце программа должна показать мне, что мое k = 1. Если бы одинаковые были 2 столбец и вторая строчка, то k равно 2. Сам я сумел только организовать вывод введённых чисел в форме матрицы.
Вот код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int i, j, N, a[20][20];
    cout << "N="; 
    cin >> N;
        
    cout << "Input matrix A \n";
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)         
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j]; 
    cout << "matrix A \n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
            
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t"; 
        cout << endl; 
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мои глаза... За что ж Вы так с людьми то? Вдруг гуманитарий зайдёт и всё, душевная травма на всю жизнь.

Comment: А по сути вопроса: покажите, что Вы сами пытались сделать, иначе Вам не помогут.

Comment: мне надо зделать ето для матрици NxN и искать я должен одинаковие строчьки и столбци также програма в конце должна вивести количество одинакових столбцов и строк например матрица 3х3 1 2 3 2 3 1 3 2 1 Вот по скольку в етой матрице одинаковие первий столбец и первая строка то в конце программа должна показать мне что мое k= 1 еслиби одинаковие били 2 столбец и вторая строчька то k ровно 2 . Сам я сумел только организовать вивод введенних чисел в форме матрици код я брошу во втором коментарии.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
 int i, j, N, M, a[20][20];
 cout << "N="; 
 cin >> N;
 cout << "M="; 
 cin >> M;
 cout << "Input matrix A \n";

 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  
  for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
   cin >> a[i][j]; 
 cout << "matrix A \n";
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
  
  for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
   cout << a[i][j] << "\t"; 
  cout << endl; 
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}`

Comment: Не надо код в комментарии пихать в таком объеме ,глаза же взрываются. Добавьте его в вопрос. Как и всю дополнительную информацию из предыдущего комментария. Для этого под вопросом есть кнопка "Править"

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int DIM = 4;

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int arr[DIM][DIM];

    // Заполнение массива
    for(int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            cin >> arr[i][j];
    
    // Вывод массива
    for(int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << ' ';
        cout << endl;
    }    
    
    cout << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
    {
        count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            if(arr[i][j] == arr[j][i])
                count++;
        if(count == DIM)
            cout << i + 1 << " строка и " << i + 1 << " столбец равны" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Как-то так... Пробуйте.

P.S. Это при условии, что И в сравниваемой строке И в сравниваемом столбце цифры НЕ повторяются (судя по вашим примерам - так и есть).

Comment: Я так понял, нужно матрицу типа 2*2? Чтобы горизонтальную строчку сравнивать с  вертикальной? Или как? Я написал только создание и заполнение матрицы. Вам ещё сравнение нужно. Распишите пример более подробно.

Comment: нет мне надо зделать ето для матрици NxN и искать я должен одинаковие строчьки и столбци также програма в конце должна вивести количество одинакових столбцов и строк например матрица 3х3   
1  2   3 
2   3   1
3    2   1 
Вот по скольку в етой матрице одинаковие первий столбец и первая строка то в конце программа должна показать мне что  мое k= 1 еслиби одинаковие били 2 столбец и вторая строчька то k ровно 2 . Сам я сумел только организовать вивод введенних чисел в форме матрици код я брошу  во втором коментарии.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
 int i, j, N, M, a[20][20];
 cout << "N="; 
 cin >> N;
 cout << "M="; 
 cin >> M;
 cout << "Input matrix A \n";

 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  
  for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
   cin >> a[i][j]; 
 cout << "matrix A \n";
 for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
 {
  
  for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
   cout << a[i][j] << "\t"; 
  cout << endl; 
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}`

Comment: @IlliaKozak одинаковых строчек и столбцов может быть несколько или только одно совпадение?

Comment: Может бить и несколько к пример мтрица 4х4 
( 1   2    3   4)
( 2   1    4   3)
( 3   4    1   2)
( 4   3    2   1)
тут мне должно вивести k= 1  k = 4

Comment: Хотя мне будет и 1 совпадение достотачьно.
Я увижу как ви зделали с 1 совпадением и если что доработаю на больше.

Comment: Используйте одну константу для размерности, матрица должна быть квадратной, иначе нет смысла сравнивать строку и столбец

Comment: Я переделал на 1 константу и поменял код в вопросе

Comment: @IlliaKozak ответ отредактировал, проверьте.

Comment: Я проверил при старте програми вилетают какието символти и все болше ничего не делает.

Comment: @IlliaKozak "какие-то символы" - это проблема с кодировкой у вас, если вы программируете в Windows. Добавьте в main() строчку setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

Comment: @IlliaKozak и прочитайте код, который написан. Не нужно просто копировать, нужно уметь понимать код.

Comment: Простите не понял сразу как код работает а можна както реализовать ввод елементов матрици и уже потом проверять на равенство ?

Comment: @IlliaKozak обновил ответ. Константой DIM регулируйте размерность массива.

Comment: Спасибо вам ви мне очень помогли .

Comment: @IlliaKozak Пожалуйста) Ответ не забывайте отмечать.